# is Tcoc can be a filter on X?

Tags: filters

Let X be intinite, then $T_{coc}$={F$\subseteq$  X: X-F is countable}. is $T_{coc}$ can be a filter on X?
i know $T_{cof}$ can be a filter on X.

Comment: For any set $X$, the set of all cocountable subsets of $X$ always forms a filter. The proof is similar to the cofinite case.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that the only non-trivial thing to check is that the intersection of two cocountable sets is cocountable - and this is true because the union of two countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a filter on $X$ for any uncountable set. And never for a countable set, obviously.  The simplest is to note that the dual is an ideal: $X$ is not in it, countable sets are closed under finite unions and subsets.

Comment: For you, is a filter always a proper filter?

Comment: @AlexKruckman of course.

Comment: @Alex: I only know of one context where "improper filter" makes sense, and that is in my framework of iterating symmetric extensions. Are there other contexts where it makes sense?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Since you asked... my preferred terminology is this: A filter on a Boolean algebra is a subset which is upwards closed, closed under meets, and contains top. In particular, the entire BA is a filter. A filter is proper if it does not contain bottom. This is in direct analogy with the standard terminology that in a ring $R$, $R$ itself is an ideal, while a proper ideal is one that does not contain $1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Here are three more justifications: (1) a filter is the preimage of $1$ under a Boolean homomorphism, and every BA admits a homomorphism to the BA with a single element. (2) a filter corresponds to the deductive closure of a theory in classical propositional logic, and there are inconsistent theories. (3) a filter corresponds to a closed set in the Stone space of a BA (the set of ultrafilters extending that filter), and the empty set is closed.